# PHP print_r and static member

Tags: php, static, visibility

I've got an instance of a *DB* object that's passed to a *Session* object, because the *Session* object has several methods that make use of *DB* object to execute SQL statements I had plan to store this *DB* object in *Session* object property.

Through testing I found that `print_r` exposed the *DB* object stored in the *Session* object property; included in the output was the db user/password.

So my idea was to store the *DB* object in a private static member, to prevent this info from being disclosed whenever `print_r` is called on the *Session* object.

Is this acceptable, or just plain bad use of static member?

What's recommended way of preventing private object property from disclosed during `print_r`?

Here's code sample.

**Before:**

```
class Session 
{

    public __construct(DB $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

}
```

**After:**

```
class Session
{

    private static $db;

    pubic __construct(DB $db)
    {
        self::$db = $db;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop print_r/var_dump/var_export from being able to read these, it has been reported several times to the php team but they consider it a feature (...) :

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39118&edit=2

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35822&edit=1

If you use a static member like in your exemple, please remember that every Session instance can access it/has the same; this can lead to some surprises later on.

Another idea is to wipe out the login/pass from the DB object once connected, this can help containing the issue.

Comment: It looks like the bug reports you linked are referring to private variables, not private static variables. I believe that static variables are not accessible from print_r/var_dump/var_export.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is bad

`print_r()` should only be used for debugging and not for displaying content to the user.

If the class contains secret information that schould not be visible to the tester, you have to sanitise (set the fields to empty string or something) the parts that are secret.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to modify the way that you're using the DB object. If a session method needs use of the DB object, they should call "global $db;" at the start of the method to ensure that sensitive DB login information is not actually part of the $_SESSION object of persistent data, and it's up to the calling page to have a proper $db object defined and not expose it during the life of that script's execution, without worrying about it hanging around in a SESSION object.